# Two custom spinner layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

I am trying to use two spinners with a custom dropdown yet, only the bottom one is showing with the custom layout when pulled down. I have been trying on my own to figure out why but I cannot.

```
public class setup extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setuplayout);
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.numberPlayers, R.layout.spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner02);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.gameDifficulty, R.layout.spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
            }
            }
```

This is the xml code for spinner_item mentioned above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:textColor="#F9B12F"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:gravity="left"  
android:padding="5dip"
android:popupBackground="#000000"
android:background="#000000"
/>
```

This is the setuplayout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/mainSetupImage"
        android:src="@drawable/setup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/players"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/players"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    </ImageView>  
    <Spinner
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
        android:textColor="#F9B12F"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/players"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner"/>
    <Spinner 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
        android:id="@+id/Spinner02"
        android:textColor="#F9B12F"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Spinner01"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/difficulty"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/difficulty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Spinner02"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/difficulty" />       


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Pls post your xml too ..

Comment: The xml is added. I assumed I made an error when coding the general java class because the other two items reference the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

in 2nd spinner u used adapter rather than adapter2. so use adapter2 and run your code hope it will run. :)

Comment: I cannot change the "adapter" phrases to be the same. I get an error regarding a duplicate local variable.

Comment: bro in setting adapter to spinner2 u used "adapter" rather than "adapter2". so replace "adapter" from "adapter2" in second spinner.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with your help. I had used the code "adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)" which was overriding my custom layout. Thanks for highlighting where the two codes were different. That was a huge help. I deleted the quoted lines and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share a little code that will make all people's code much cleaner when making ArrayAdapters.

Just define a static method in a class of your preference (even MainActivity...)  to give you the Array adapter without dirting so much your code:

```
 public static ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> 
     getArrayAdapter( Context c,  int arrayId, int idLayout1, int idLayout2){
     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aa;
     aa = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( c, arrayId , idLayout1);
     aa.setDropDownViewResource( idLayout2);
     return aa;     
}
```

Then in your code you just need to do it:

```
myspinner.addAdapter(
      this, ThatClass.getArrayAdapter( 
             R.array.myid, R.layout.id1, R.layout.id2 );
myspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

/* Remember that the default Android Spinner layout can be get passing these specific layout ids:
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item as layout1 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item as layout2
*/
```